# Select button to Run function

Tags: javascript, html

```
 <table class="calc" cellpadding=2> 
        <td><input type="button" class="calc" id="screen" value="0" ></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="calc" id="screen" value="0" ></td>
        <tr>
    </table>
    <table class="calc" cellpadding=2> 
        <td><button type="button" onclick="pushButton(1)" value="Call2Functions">1</td>
        <td><button type="button" onclick="pushButton(2)" value="Call2Functions">2</td>
        <td><button type="button" onclick="pushButton(3)" value="Call2Functions">3</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <div>

        <script> 
            function pushButton(buttonValue) {
    if (buttonValue == 'C') {
        document.getElementById('screen').value = '0';
    }
    else {//this is where most changes occured
        var x= document.getElementById('screen').value 
        x =parseInt(x)+ parseInt(buttonValue);
        document.getElementById('screen').value=x;
        localStorage.setItem('answer', x);
    }
}

    function calculate(equation) {
        var answer = eval(equation);
        document.getElementById('screen').value = answer;
    }
                         </script>
```

Hello Friends,
pls help me.. My question is very clear.if suppose you and friend playing one by one by clicking numbers..first you click numbers it should get stored locally in the first button.then your friend clicking the same buttons but now it should be reflected in the second button.then again if you pressed buttons it should be added in the first button..So how to do this and every time i clicked i should be stored locally so i do not loss my data

Comment: Never use the same ID for multiple elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript Code is...

```
function pushButton(buttonValue) {
    if (buttonValue == 'C') {
        document.getElementById('screen').value = '0';
    }
    else {//this is where most changes occured
        var x= document.getElementById('screen'+buttonValue).value 
        x =parseInt(x)+ parseInt(buttonValue);
        document.getElementById('screen'+buttonValue).value=x;
        localStorage.setItem('answer', x);
    }
}

function calculate(equation) {
    var answer = eval(equation);
    document.getElementById('screen'+buttonValue).value = answer;
}
```

And HTML code is here...

```
<table class="calc" cellpadding=2> 
    <tr>
        <td><input type="button" class="calc" id="screen1" value="0"></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="calc" id="screen2" value="0"></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="calc" id="screen3" value="0"></td>
        </tr>
</table>
<table class="calc" cellpadding=2>
    <tr> 
        <td><button type="button" onclick="pushButton(1)" value="Call2Functions">1</td>
        <td><button type="button" onclick="pushButton(2)" value="Call2Functions">2</td>
        <td><button type="button" onclick="pushButton(3)" value="Call2Functions">3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

For reff. purpose have look at [my plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hKFl26NcqWaVJMJ427t3?p=preview)

Comment: @ shatakshi ,hi thanks for you reply.But actually may i wrongly communicated.what i want is to add some checkbox button or select button just below to the existing buttons(if its a checkbox).if suppose i select 1st check box whenever i click number buttons it should be get added in the first button.if suppose i select the second checkbox the button values need to be added in the second button like wise..

Comment: okay i got your point what you want to say. i have done according to you what you want just see the new plnkr of mine link is here....http://plnkr.co/edit/hKFl26NcqWaVJMJ427t3?p=preview  . I hope you get you answer.

Comment: Hi @shatakshi i got it but its not stored locally(localStorage),

Comment: @Sufian can you help me? i got it but i am unable to store locally